# how to customize ec2 instance at launch time

Tags: bash, api, amazon-ec2, automation, boto

I am trying to launch ec2 spot instance using aws api in python, so just wondering if there is any way to format all ephemeral drive and mount the on /mnt/ephemeral0, .... /mnt/ephemeraln at the time instance launch ?
or how to provide script which does this at the time of launch ?

I tried to pass my following script in USER DATA but it didn't worked.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a ephemeral_list
for mount in $(lsblk | grep ^x | awk '{ print $1 }') 
do
   if ! mount | grep $mount >/dev/null; then
      ephemeral_list+=($mount)
   fi   
done

for i in "${!ephemeral_list[@]}"
do
#  echo "${mount}"
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${ephemeral_list[$i]}"
  [ -d /mnt/ephemeral$i ] || mkdir /mnt/ephemeral$i
  mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard /dev/${ephemeral_list[$i]}
  mount /dev/${ephemeral_list[$i]} /mnt/ephemeral$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

[user-data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) is what you are looking for. There is extensive information about user-data on AWS documentation site and on [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=AWS%20User-data&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=NYkCVbavD5DluQSZh4HYDw).